# finding recaptcha callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, recaptcha, captcha

im trying to get data from this page

https://ahrefs.com/backlink-checker

its basically a website to check a domain rank and other status ,  when u enter a domain and click the check `Check backlinks` button it shows a google recaptcha

im using a captcha service to bypass this , problem is this site uses a callback on the captcha completion ,  when i recive the token from my api and put it in the `#g-recaptcha-response` i have to call the callback to move on there is no submit button

i used to find the callback in this object

`___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback`

and just call it like

```
page.evaluate(`___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback("${cap}")`)
```

but recently this obeject is nowhere to be found

and i get 
`Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'L' of undefined`

any idea?

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at that page and the captcha isn't there.

Comment: @pguardiario you have to click on the orange button for captcha to show up

Comment: this [forum](https://captchaforum.com/threads/problem-with-invisible-recaptcha-v2-callback-function-at-mail-com-sign-up-page.56/) helped a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I checked that url and when the captcha was there on the screen, then the object inside `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]` where callback was available was different i.e., `L` was not there on `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]`, that's why you might have got the error. So thought of navigating to the `callback` object based on the type rather than directly accessing.

```js
const client = ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]
const keys = Object.keys(client)
const requiredKey = keys.find(key => client[key].constructor.name === "VK");

const requiredObj = client[requiredKey];

const callbackObjKey = Object.keys(requiredObj).find(key => requiredObj[key].callback);
requiredObj[callbackObjKey].callback("${cap}")
```

Hope this helps.

[image]
I have modified the code and used below approach to find the `callback` object, though this method is not so optimised but this is the way I could think to find out the `callback` method

```js
const reduceObjectToArray = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r.concat(k, obj[k]);
}, []);

const client = ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]
let result = [];
result = reduceObjectToArray(client).filter(c => Object.prototype.toString.call(c) === "[object Object]")

result = result.flatMap(r => {
    return reduceObjectToArray(r)
})

result = result.filter(c => Object.prototype.toString.call(c) === "[object Object]")

const reqObj = result.find( r => r.callback)
reqObj.callback("${cap}")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it would be great if i can search for the callback in the object  , but it doesn't seem to work ... i get `VM531:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined`  maybe u meant to write `const requiredObj = client[requiredKey ]` ? but i also get undefined when i console.log `requiredKey `

Comment: Yes. I meant that. Sorry it was a typo. I have updated my answer. Thanks for the intimation. 
Oh, for me it's working, I have checked in Chrome as well as in Safari. One point to be noted over here is, you'll get the value only when the captcha is available on the screen. Otherwise `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]` will be `undefined`

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(requiredKey)` ? it should be a string ... name of the key right ? i get `undefined` and i think thats the problem without the key there is no  object  ... i've added a pic to my question pleas take a look

Comment: Oh. Looks completely strange, I have tested this in different browsers and still getting the  string when I do `console.log(requiredKey)`, I have updated the answer with a screenshot. What I'm wondering is the type of the object is also getting changed or different for you and me?

Comment: Modified my answer with another approach, I know it's not so optimised solution. But I'm hoping this works without any issues. Please try it out once.

Comment: i think google changes the object structure based on different factors , im going to work with your code and see what happens

Comment: In updated code we are not checking any type except `[object Object]`. It's really strange even after that it's not working :-(. 
Along with the code I have attached the screenshot for the same with updated code.

Comment: the updated code worked ! thanx ... and i just put a bounty on the question : ))

Comment: @hretic Is the callback still working? I was doing something similar and though I would ask